# urllib not raising invalid URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting some curious behaviour parsing when parsing a URL. I was expecting to receive an invalid URL exception, but instead, the hostname of the following URL returns the URL in '`[]`' brackets:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
print(urlparse('http://myurl.com[notmyurl.com]').hostname)
```

Output:

```py
>>> notmyurl.com
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior running your code through a debugger and stepping through the steps in the `parse.py` of `urllib` we see the following

```
@property
def _hostinfo(self):
    netloc = self.netloc
    _, _, hostinfo = netloc.rpartition('@')
    _, have_open_br, bracketed = hostinfo.partition('[')
    if have_open_br:
        hostname, _, port = bracketed.partition(']')
        _, _, port = port.partition(':')
    else:
        hostname, _, port = hostinfo.partition(':')
    if not port:
        port = None
    return hostname, port
```

So you can see the `_hostinfo` method call will check for brackets in the url in return you the value from inside the brackets. Below is a screen shot of running your code through the pycharm debugger as you see in the code window it tells you the value set for each parameter and where is starts striping out the not url to return.

[image]

Comment: I suppose I'm also wondering why this behaviour is expected over raising an InvalidUrl exception

Comment: Actually after a bit of reading it seems related to IPv6 address literals in urls. So normal ip in url would be written as `http://192.168.100.20:8080` you can just write the ip as the hostname. But for IPv6 you need to put the address inside square brackets like `http://[3ffe:2a00:100:7031::1]:8080`

Comment: So the brackets are needed in the IPv6 address since it's using `:` as it's separators instead of `. ` like in ipv4. And since `:` is used as the separator for hostname and port we need a way to separate IPv6 address and port. So seems the way to do it is wrap the IPv6 address in a quare brackets

Comment: Seems every day is a learning day as I didn't know any of this till I seen your question

Comment: Interesting, I can see why that's important. Glad you're learning something, I sure am! Feel free to upvote the question if it's helped ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah forgot that. Nice question